# Weird difference between colours - UINavigationBar and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to modify my code to change colour of UINavigationBar and UISearchBar.

For some odd reason, the same instance of UIColor provide different results. Please take a look at screen:

[image]

There is the code for customise appearance:

```
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithR:88 G:123 B:139 A:1];
   [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:color];
   [[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:color];
```

`ColorWithR` is a simple category that simplify process of getting colour using RGB. As you can see, i have same colour but if you look at screen, it different. How could this happen?

PS. Im sorry for this extremely large screenshot, i was unable to figure out how to make it small.

Comment: is the search bar or the navigation bar set transparent?

Comment: I remove checkmark from transparent in story board, and tried to remove it from owner class (SearchViewController) setting it to NO. Still, no effect.

Comment: This is a tableViewcontroller embed in a navigation controller right? and the search bar is added in the tableviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes it is, i ember it in navigation controller.

Comment: Is [this QA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1808/_index.html) useful for your case?

Comment: I don't think so, i already have RGB colour.

Comment: Check your code carefully. You might set something somewhere else that is not the 3 lines of code provided...